# Does pg promise support WITH clause in query file?

Tags: pg-promise

If I put this in one query file how will pg promise handle it?

```
WITH regional_sales AS (
        SELECT region, SUM(amount) AS total_sales
        FROM orders
        GROUP BY region
     ), top_regions AS (
        SELECT region
        FROM regional_sales
        WHERE total_sales > (SELECT SUM(total_sales)/10 FROM regional_sales)
     )
SELECT region,
       product,
       SUM(quantity) AS product_units,
       SUM(amount) AS product_sales
FROM orders
WHERE region IN (SELECT region FROM top_regions)
GROUP BY region, product;
```

Is there a need to use WITH at all? I want to have the following use case,

`SELECT * FROM balance WHERE bank_id = 1 FOR UPDATE` (force all bank id 1 record to be locked)

`SELECT * FROM balance WHERE bank_id = 1 AND amount = 500` (just get rows with bank id 1, but still making sure all bank id records 1 are locked`

Answer (score 0):

[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) doesn't care what your SQL is made of, simply sending it into the server as is.

...which makes your question irrelevant/invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I jsut cant find any example of people using WITH clause with pg promise. In your opinion, can WITH clause be totally avoided?

Comment: @Zanko Your question has no relevance to `pg-promise` whatsoever. And there are lots of examples that can be found on GitHub where developers execute `WITH` queries via `pg-promise`, which again is of no relation to each other.